# Is iterative dependency search and best first searches have the same meaning?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

If not then what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

These are not directly comparable terms, although they do overlap in application at times.

**Best-first** search is exactly what it appears to be: at each iteration of your process (often finding the next graph node to explore), you examine the node with the highest evaluation.  This evaluation could be a distance, a heuristic estimate, or any other "best" metric operating in the paradigm.

In many applications, any potential solution or partial solution is compared to the best known.  Unless it's at least as good, the potential / partial solution is pruned from the search tree.  Dijkstra's algorithm is an example of this.

---

**Iterative dependency** is simply a standard approach for obtaining the closure of a sub-graph.  At each iteration, choose any convenient edge from any node in the sub-graph to any outside node.  Traverse that node and include it in the sub-graph.  If there are no such edges, then the sub-graph closure is complete.

---

The two terms do not mean the same thing.  However, if the "convenient edge" of iterative dependency is the "best" transition to make from the sub-graph, *and* the sub-graph's closure includes a solution state, then the two can be equivalent in practice.